# Chrome Extension View Optional Permission Warnings Locally

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to add optional permissions to my extension and would like to test the warning messages (locally) prior to publishing.

I followed [this](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/permission_warnings/#view_warnings) article, and created the packed `.crx` file.

However when I upload it (via drag and drop), I get:

> This extension is not listed in the Chrome Web Store and may have been added without your knowledge. Learn More

...but, my [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabmerger/inmiajapbpafmhjleiebcamfhkfnlgoc?hl=en) IS listed in the Chrome Webstore.

Am I missing something, or did Chrome permanently disable `.crx` uploads?

Seems like there is no solution to this online.

Is it possible that my "updated" manifest is causing this issue as it is now using `v3` whereas the published extension is `v2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, you can use [`chrome.management.getPermissionWarningsByManifest`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/management/#method-getPermissionWarningsByManifest).

It can be ran from any extension (without the `"management"` permission, and not necessarily the extension you're testing for warnings) and takes a valid extension manifest file as a string, returning an array of warnings in callback.

An example using the manifest of the extension as linked in your question:

```js
const m = `
{
    "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "2.0.0",
    (..skipped..)
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "contextMenus",
        "storage",
        "alarms",
        "downloads",
        "downloads.shelf"
    ],
    (..skipped..)
}`;

chrome.management.getPermissionWarningsByManifest(
  m, 
  warnings => { for (let warning of warnings) console.log(warning); }
);
// Prints:
//  Read your browsing history
//  Manage your downloads
```

Comment: So this means that `.crx` files are not permitted in general?

If I understand your proposed workaround correctly, let's say I have `alarms` as an "optional permission". It needs to be added when the user clicks a button. When the user does finally click the button, I use `chrome.permissions.request` and in the background I listen to the `chrome.permissions.onAdded` event. Inside the `onAdded` event I can then use the `chrome.management.getPermissionWarningsByManifest` to log all the warnings (for debugging purposes) if in "development" environment?

Comment: Upon closer inspection, it seem like `alarms` does not trigger a dialog for addition. I also tried with `downloads` and I do see the warning even when I load an "unpacked" version. Here is a list of what seems to be supported: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/permission_warnings/#permissions_with_warnings